# How to make the function only runs once in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

How to make the function only runs once per button?
if clicks in "click me" only works once, and the same for the other buttons
Order not to put much code, I put an example..:
  http://jsbin.com/apexod/1/watch

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="hello()"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me1" onclick="hello()"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me2" onclick="hello()">
<script>
   function hello(){
       alert("hello");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the onclick

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="hello(this)"><br>
    <input type="button" value="click1" onclick="hello(this)"><br>
    <input type="button" value="click2" onclick="hello(this)">
<script>
       function hello(btn){ 
           alert("hello");
           btn.onclick = function(){};
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your `onclick` handlers so that the function can reference the element clicked.

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="hello.call(this)"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me1" onclick="hello.call(this)"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me2" onclick="hello.call(this)">
```

Then change the function to remove the handler.

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello");
    this.onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: Does the hello.call act on the element? I would expect you to do `hello(this)` and have `function hello(but) { but.onclick=null }` - ah, as I see the accepted answer does

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, using `.call(this)` is setting the `this` value of the function to the current `this`. I prefer it over `hello(this)` because it allows the function to behave like typical event handlers where `this` is a reference to the element. You can also do `hello.call(this, event)`, and it will pass along the `event` object... even in IE.

Comment: Amazing how I learn something new every day... I asked because I just rejected someone's attempt to "fix" your code with an edit.

Comment: @mplungjan: Yeah, I noticed that. Thanks for rejecting it. :)

Comment: I hardly ever use inline handlers anymore, but a good thing to know. First time I see it.

Answer (score 2):

It’s easier to manage if you add event listeners in the script (it’s also consider good practice to separate behaviour from presentation):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4N4ur/

```
<input type="button" value="click">
<input type="button" value="click1">
<input type="button" value="click2">​

<script>
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = function() {
        hello();
        this.onclick = null; // reset the handler
    }
}
function hello() {
    alert('hello';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> on click of buttton call the function below with button id or name as param

```
    <script>
       function hello(caller){
          if (caller == 'button1' && $("#button1clicked").val() != '1')
          {
         // Your code to execute for the function
         alert("hello");
       // set value for button1clicked
       $("#button1clicked").val("1");
       }else {
       // do nothing
       }

     }
     </script>
```

Add the above conditions for no of buttons

Answer (score 1):

While the above scenario and answers are all very specific to click handlers, the answer to the original question `how to make a function that only runs once` is generally done using a wrapper function, similar to the UnderscoreJS `.once` method:

```
function once(fn) {
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

The above implementation would only allow the original function to be invoked once, and it would pass through the context and arguments of the later invocation. This would then be used as:

```
var oneTimeFn = once(function() {
  console.log('I was called.');
});

oneTimeFn();
//-> I was called.

oneTimeFn();
//-> undefined
```